# Delete the last node of a doublyarrayList with an iterator

Tags: c++, list, iterator, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to delete the last node when I call `remove()` and my current is at the last node.

Each time I am trying to delete the last node, my current and last nodes should be the new last node. But, instead, my last node is deleted.

Can someone explain me with an example what I should do instead?

I am able to get the first and last nodes with those methods `Node<TYPE>* getLast()`

Here is my code from now with error:

```cpp
Node<TYPE>* elementToDelete = currentNode;
this->currentNode = currentNode->getPrevious();

Node<TYPE>* newLastNode = currentNode;
Node<TYPE>* nullLastNode = list->getLast()->getNext();
list->getLast()->getPrevious()->setNext(newLastNode);
            
newLastNode->setNext(nullLastNode);
            
delete elementToDelete;
list->decreaseSize();
```

My list

```
#pragma once
#include "List.h"
#include "Node.hpp"

template <class TYPE>
class DoubleLinkedList : public List<TYPE>
{
public:
    DoubleLinkedList()
    {
        this->first = nullptr;
        this->last = nullptr;
        this->nbElements = 0;
    }

    ~DoubleLinkedList()
    {
        while (!isEmpty())
            pop();
    }

    void push(const TYPE& content) override
    {
        Node<TYPE>* newNodeAdded = new Node<TYPE>(content);
        //Si vide
        if (this->last == nullptr)
        {
            this->last = newNodeAdded;
            this->first = last;

            //C'est le seul endroit ou on va ajouter les deux nodes spéciaux
            this->last->setPrevious(new Node<TYPE>(BOFile, true));
            this->last->getPrevious()->setNext(last);

            this->last->setNext(new Node<TYPE>(EOFile, true));
            //fin ajout nodes spéciaux
        }
        //Sinon fin
        else
        {
            newNodeAdded->setNext(last->getNext());
            newNodeAdded->setPrevious(this->last);

            //Gestion d'un node spécial
            this->last->setNext(newNodeAdded);

            this->last = this->last->getNext();
        }

        this->last->getNext()->setPrevious(last);
        enlargeSize();
    }

    void pop() override
    {
        if (isEmpty()) throw EmptyListException();

        Node<TYPE>* temp = this->first;
        this->first = temp->getNext();
        //Si dernier element
        if (temp == this->last)
        {
            this->last = nullptr;

            //on pop le dernier node alors on efface les deux nodes spéciaux
            delete temp->getNext();
            delete temp->getPrevious();
            //fin gestion effacement
        }
        //Sinon
        else
        {
            //Avant c'était setPrevious(nullptr);  Maintenant on gère les nodes spéciaux
            this->first->setPrevious(temp->getPrevious());
            this->first->getPrevious()->setNext(first);
        }
        delete temp;
        decreaseSize();
    }

    TYPE& front() override
    {
        if (isEmpty()) throw EmptyListException();

        return *first->getContent();
    }

    TYPE& back() override
    {
        if (isEmpty()) throw EmptyListException();

        return *(last->getContent());
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return this->nbElements == 0;
    }

    void enlargeSize() 
    {
        this->nbElements++;
    }

    void decreaseSize() 
    {
        this->nbElements--;
    }

    int size() const override
    {
        return this->nbElements;
    }

    Node<TYPE>* getFirst()
    {
        if (isEmpty()) throw EmptyListException();

        return first;
    }

    Node<TYPE>* getLast()
    {
        if (isEmpty()) throw EmptyListException();

        return last;
    }

private:
    Node<TYPE>* first;
    Node<TYPE>* last;
    int nbElements;
};
```

My nodes

```
#pragma once
static const int BOFile = -1;
static const int EOFile = 1;

template <class TYPE>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(const TYPE& content)
    {
        setContent(content);
        this->next = nullptr;
        this->previous = nullptr;
        this->extremityStatus = 0;
    }

    Node(int extremityStatus, bool failsafe)  //Le booléen est parce que si le template est int la signature devient ambigue
    {
        content = nullptr;
        this->next = nullptr;
        this->previous = nullptr;
        this->extremityStatus = extremityStatus;
    }

    ~Node()
    {
        if (content != nullptr)
            delete content;
    }

    Node* getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    void setNext(Node* next)
    {
        this->next = next;
    }

    Node* getPrevious()
    {
        return previous;
    }

    void setPrevious(Node* previous)
    {
        this->previous = previous;
    }

    TYPE* getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }

    void setContent(const TYPE& content)
    {
        this->content = new TYPE(content);
    }

    bool isBOFNode()
    {
        return extremityStatus == BOFile;
    }

    bool isEOFNode()
    {
        return extremityStatus == EOFile;
    }

private:
    Node* next = nullptr;
    Node* previous = nullptr;
    TYPE* content = nullptr;
    int extremityStatus = 0;
};
```

Comment: You haven't shown nearly enough of your code.  We have no idea how you've implemented the various member functions, and we don't know what your `Node` type looks like, nor whether `list` is also a `Node` or its own structure.  The main thing I see is a lack of NULL-testing, which may or may not be important depending on the preconditions that lead to the bit of code that you've shown.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things a bit. Draw a picture of a small list and then redraw the list as you, link-by-link, remove the node you want gone.

Comment: @paddy here are all my classes, I can't change push or pop, everything needs to be in the remove and insert in remove and insert

Comment: The program would be a lot less verbose and have tighter encapsulation if `Node` declares `List` as a friend.  This is an appropriate use of `friend`, because the classes have a functional coupling.  Public methods to set linkage pointers on a node are inappropriate and should not be exposed.  The "extremityStatus" is also puzzling.  It does not seem to belong in the node at all.  That kind of thing should have nothing to do with list maintenance, and would be better bundled with a struct by whichever list user requires it.

Comment: What is a "doublyarraylist"?  Are you talking an array of doubly linked lists?  Are you talking about a doubly-linked-list that acts like an array?

Answer (score 2):

When `currentNode` is pointing at the last node, you need to tell the `list` to update its `last` pointer, but your code is not attempting to do that.  You are also not updating the `list`'s `first` pointer if the `list` only has 1 node in it, thus you are effectively making the list empty.

When deleting *any* node from a double-linked list, you can use logic that is more like this instead:

```cpp
Node<TYPE>* elementToDelete = currentNode;
currentNode = elementToDelete->getNext();

if (elementToDelete->getNext())
    elementToDelete->getNext()->setPrevious(elementToDelete->getPrevious());

if (elementToDelete->getPrevious())
    elementToDelete->getPrevious()->setNext(elementToDelete->getNext());

if (list->getLast() == elementToDelete)
    list->setLast(elementToDelete->getPrevious());

if (list->getFirst() == elementToDelete)
    list->setFirst(elementToDelete->getNext());

delete elementToDelete;
list->decreaseSize();
```

Which, if you *know* the `currentNode` is the last node, is effectively this:

```cpp
Node<TYPE>* elementToDelete = ...;
currentNode = nullptr;

if (elementToDelete->getPrevious())
    elementToDelete->getPrevious()->setNext(nullptr);

list->setLast(elementToDelete->getPrevious());

if (list->getFirst() == elementToDelete)
    list->setFirst(nullptr);

delete elementToDelete;
list->decreaseSize();
```

That being said, this kind of logic really belongs inside a method of your `list` class, not in outside code that is iterating the list.

Comment: I don't understand the (elementToDelete->getNext()). What does it mean?

Comment: It is doing a null-test.  A non-null value evaluates to `true` and null value evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it in class. I am only learning this language this pasts months

Comment: @NicolasPellerin `if (elementToDelete->getNext())` is shorthand for `if (elementToDelete->getNext() != nullptr)` in this case